# Names of variables are stored in bash array; how to loop over the array and test their values against common pattern?

Tags: bash, array

Team,

I am trying to implement a functionality that check content of all variables in list of predefined variables in ENV by user and then run my function with all the resulted variables as parameters.

so, there are 3 possibilities:

```
1 - All variables hold same value 
[DatasetSize & BlockSize == DEFAULT ]

2 - All variables hold unique value 
[DatasetSize & BlockSize != DEFAULT ]

3 - Some are unique and some distinct. 
[DatasetSize || BlockSize = DEFAULT ]
```

my code is below working for case1 and 2 but not for 3rd. For 3rd case when anyone of the variable has 'DEFAULT' its just executing 2nd elif and not 3rd one.

```
#!/bin/bash
#exit on fail without running next command
set -eo pipefail

export TestType="read"
export IOEngine="psync"
export DatasetSize="DEFAULT"
export BlockSize="NON-DEFAULT"

preset="DEFAULT"
declare -a static_vars=(TestType IOEngine)
declare -a dynamic_vars=(DatasetSize BlockSize )
declare -a vars=(TestType IOEngine DatasetSize BlockSize)

for var_name in "${vars[@]}"
do
  if [ -z "$(eval "echo \$$var_name")" ]; then
    echo "Missing environment variable $var_name"
    exit 1
  fi
done

overwrite_all() {
    printf "all defaults in func\n"
}
overwrite_some() {
    printf "some defaults in func\n"
}
overwrite_none() {
    printf " none defaults in func\n"
}
overwrite() {
    #not sure how to overwrite only those vars that have nonDEFAULT value.
    export DatasetSize="changed"
    export BlockSize="changed"
    echo "DatasetSize=$DatasetSize BlockSize=$BlockSize"
}
if [[ "$IOEngine" == "psync"  && ( "$TestType" == "read" || "$TestType" == "randread" ) ]]; then
    iter=1
    while [ $iter -lt 2 ]
    do
        echo "all are defaults; being to call your script with these parameters"
        echo $var_name
        if [[ ${dynamic_vars[@]} == $preset ]]; then
            echo "calling over_none"
            overwrite_none
        elif [[ ${dynamic_vars[@]} != "DEFAULT" ]]; then
            echo "calling over_all"
            overwrite_all
            overwrite
        elif [[ $DatasetSize == "DEFAULT" || $BlockSize == "DEFAULT" ]] && [[ $DatasetSize != "DEFAULT" && $BlockSize != "DEFAULT" ]]; then
                echo "calling over_some"
                overwrite_some
                overwrite
            else
            echo "done"
        fi
            iter=$[$iter+1]
        done
    else
        echo "ITengine not found"
    fi
    echo "out of loop"
```

output:

```
calling over_all
all non-defaults in func
Data setSize=changed BlockSize=changed
out of loop
```

expect output:

```
some defaults in func
DatasetSize=changed BlockSize=changed
```

Comment: no it does not. this question is about while loop.

Comment: Yeah, muy bad: I adjusted. I am not getting endless loop. I have pasted my actual output above and code.

Comment: Okay, I just added my whole script and its expected output. but i don't know how to handle case ELIF 3

Comment: where is your edit?

Comment: https://superuser.com/posts/1444568/revisions

Comment: I placed code correcting errors. and also update new output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will address what I think is the main flaw in your code. It's in lines like this one:

> ```
> if [[ ${dynamic_vars[@]} == $preset ]]; then
> ```

The fragment `[[ ${dynamic_vars[@]} == $preset ]]` in your case is equivalent to

```
[[ "DatasetSize BlockSize" == DEFAULT ]]
```

and this doesn't fit your desired logic at all. Issues:

1. (Minor issue or by design). Unquoted right hand side of `==` operator inside `[[ … ]]` is treated as a pattern. `DEFAULT` doesn't contain `*` nor so, so it doesn't matter in this case; but in general you may want to double-quote `$preset`.
2. Unquoted `${array[@]}` undergoes word splitting like unquoted `$string` does. If you set this:

   ```
   array=(nospace "with space")
   string="nospace with space"
   ```

   then `${array[@]}` will expand to three entities, so will `$string`. But `"${array[@]}"` will expand to *two* entities, while `"$string"` will expand to one entity. You can test this yourself with the following code:

   ```
   sh -c 'echo $#' whatever ${array[@]}
   sh -c 'echo $#' whatever $string
   sh -c 'echo $#' whatever "${array[@]}"
   sh -c 'echo $#' whatever "$string"
   ```

   This means you virtually always want to use `"${array[@]}"` because the whole point of arrays is to pass an exact number of arguments (here: 2) some of which may include spaces or such.

   Your particular array contains names of variables. In general such names cannot include spaces nor few other characters, this makes them safe (even if there's filename expansion involved, I think). You could put them in a (space separated) `string` or in an `array` and retrieve by `${array[@]}`, `"${array[@]}"` or `$string` (but not `"$string"`). Still this is an exception and it only works because names of variables are constrained.

   So your `${dynamic_vars[@]}` normally expands to two entities (as `"${dynamic_vars[@]}"` normally would). There's a catch though: unquoted variables inside `[[ … ]]` are treated as single entities anyway (this is special to `[[ … ]]`), hence `"DatasetSize BlockSize"`.

   Note if you did `[[ "${dynamic_vars[@]}" == "$preset" ]]`, this would "work" like

   ```
   [[ "DatasetSize" "BlockSize" == "DEFAULT" ]]
   ```

   which is syntactically wrong (there should be exactly one argument on either side of `==`).

   But neither `[[ "DatasetSize BlockSize" == DEFAULT ]]` nor `[[ "DatasetSize" "BlockSize" == "DEFAULT" ]]` (nor even `[[ "DatasetSize" == "DEFAULT" && "BlockSize" == "DEFAULT" ]]`, if you got to this somehow) is what you want. This leads us to the next point.
3. Your `dynamic_vars` array contains strings, not variables nor their values. I mean you can easily get `DatasetSize` (i.e. the literal `DatasetSize` string) from it. This is obviously different from what `$DatasetSize` would expand to (i.e. the string `DEFAULT`). You need an *additional* level of expansion before you compare the result to `$preset`.

   You actually perform additional expansion elsewhere. In this snippet:

   > ```
   > for var_name in "${vars[@]}"
   > do
   >   if [ -z "$(eval "echo \$$var_name")" ]; then
   >     echo "Missing environment variable $var_name"
   >     exit 1
   >   fi
   > done
   > ```

   `eval "echo \$$var_name"` is a cumbersome way to expand a variable whose name is stored in another variable (the term is *indirect expansion*). In Bash there is special syntax for this: `${!var_name}` (and usually you want to double-quote this). The relevant line can be

   ```
   if [ -z "${!var_name}" ]; then
   ```

   Note `"$(eval "echo \$$var_name")"` is [dangerous](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/250178/108618). If the final variable is under someone else's control, they can inject code into your script. `"${!var_name}"` is safe in this matter.

   Also in this snippet you used `for var_name in "${vars[@]}"`. This is a good way to iterate over an array. You could have used this approach to test every name in `"${dynamic_vars[@]}"` later in your code.

---

Putting this all together, you can get what you want by counting the number of variables that hold the default value; like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

DatasetSize="DEFAULT"
BlockSize="NON-DEFAULT"

preset="DEFAULT"
declare -a dynamic_vars=( DatasetSize BlockSize )

number_of_dynamic_vars="${#dynamic_vars[@]}"
number_of_default_values=0

for var in "${dynamic_vars[@]}"
do
  [[ "${!var}" == "$preset" ]] && ((number_of_default_values++))
done

if [[ "$number_of_default_values" -eq 0 ]]; then
  echo "No defaults"
elif [[ "$number_of_default_values" -eq "$number_of_dynamic_vars" ]]; then
  echo "All defaults"
else
  echo "Mixed"
fi
```

The general algorithm can be rebuild (optimized), so "Mixed" is announces as soon as possible (best case scenario: after testing the first two variables). However for only few variables this is not worth the effort; and for two variables (or less) you always need to check them all.

Note I'm not testing (`if`) in your original order. I'm testing against `0` (your possibility number 2) before `$number_of_dynamic_vars` (possibility 1). This way, if the `dynamic_vars` array had exactly 0 elements, I would get "No defaults" instead of "All defaults". It's only because in this *edge case* I'd like to see "No defaults". But if "No defaults" implied lot of extra work and "All defaults" didn't, I'd like to put this edge case in the "All defaults" basket (i.e. test against `$number_of_dynamic_vars` first).

---

Additional notes:

- [`[` and `[[` are different](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47576482/10765659). In most cases I used `[[` even if `[` could suffice.
- I double-quoted variables inside `[[ … ]]`, even though in many cases quoting is not required. My premise is "always quote your variables unless you know what you're doing and have a good reason not to". There are only *few* cases where you mustn't quote to get what you want; there are cases where quoting doesn't matter; and there are *many* cases where [lack of proper quoting will bite you](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/108618).

Comment: Awesome!. Not sure how to thank you but works, I am still digesting your logic. 
A clarification I have is why u did not chose elif to if in second check of No defaults

Comment: I have a follow up logic to be added. shall i put up a new question or continue here? basically, for those variables that are mixed, i want to identify them uniquely and then use them as parameters + the remaining default ones in running another script. so script parameters are all these variables

Comment: New question, definitely. I deliberately let you fix minor flaws in the current question, so finally it became a question about *one specific problem* (and my recent edit summarizes this problem in the title). Achieving such state is very good, the question is now potentially useful for future users with similar problems; this is what Stack Exchange is about. From now on edits should not substantially alter the question. I can see you've already added a new question. Maybe I'll meet you there.